# Call to a member function insert() on a non-object, codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, insert

I am trying to insert data to mysql in codeigniter. Controller class :

```
class Ci_insert extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function index()
        {
            $data = array(
                          "USN" => "TRE5rCS89G",
                          "name" => "NITISH DOLAKASHARIA",
                          "branch" => "CS"
                          );

            $this->load->model('ci_insert_model');

            $this->ci_insert_model->addToDb($data);
        }

    }
```

Model Class :

```
class ci_insert_model extends CI_Model
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function addToDb($data)
        {

            //var_dump($data);
            $this->db->insert('class_record',$data);
        }
    }
```

But when I tried to run the code, it shows `Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter\application\models\ci_insert_model.php on line 12`.

Whats wrong with the code above?

Comment: Do not use `ci_` as the prefix for a class, that is reserved for codeigniter native classes. From docs: *Please note that all native CodeIgniter libraries are prefixed with CI_ so DO NOT use that as your prefix.*

Comment: are you auto loading database library ?

Answer (score 10):

You're missing `$this->load->database();`

`$this->db->method_name();` will only work when the database library is loaded.

If you plan on using the database throughout your application, I would suggest adding it to your `autoload.php` in `/application/config/`.

As others have mentioned, remove the `CI_` prefix from your class names. `CI_` is reserved for framework classes.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `'$this->load->library('database')'` in the model before `'$this->db->insert()'`  or 
autoload the database library. Go to config folder select autoload.php search for $autoload['libraries'] and replace your empty array() with array('database').

Answer (score 3):

Add  autoload libraries in config folder open autoload.php and set `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');`

Answer (score 1):

Try out.

Controller : insert.php

```
class Insert extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data = array(
                      "USN" => "TRE5rCS89G",
                      "name" => "NITISH DOLAKASHARIA",
                      "branch" => "CS"
                      );

        $this->load->model('insert_model');

        $this->insert_model->addToDb($data);
    }

}
```

Model: insert_model.php

```
class Insert_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function addToDb($data)
    {

        //var_dump($data);
        $this->db->insert('class_record',$data);
    }
}
```

Please write capital first latter of class, don't add prefix like `ci_`.